# How does autoComplete work with Options for commands?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I want the user to be able to auto complete the **finishDate** value with *"MM/dd/yyyy HH"*
But i cannot find it anywhere on how to set it up.

This is what the command looks like rn:

```
jda.getGuildById(guild.getId()).upsertCommand("lottery", "Creates a lottery in the current or selected channel.")
     .addOption(OptionType.STRING, "reward", "The reward for the lottey winners", true)
     .addOption(OptionType.STRING, "finishDate", "Use format MM/dd/yyyy HH", true, true);
```

Comment: Check this https://jda.wiki/using-jda/interactions/#handling-autocomplete You'll have to implement the actual completion logic yourself.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks! Also the website is amazing <3